# How to output the result of an Impala query along with the query

Tags: io-redirection, impala

Is there a way to output the result of an Impala query along with the query?

For example, if my query was `'show databases'`, I'd like to output the result to a file with something like this:

```
Query: show databases
Result: ------default-------
```

When I run `impala-shell -i someip -f 'filename' -o 'output'`, I only see the results, one after one, so it's difficult to correlate which result goes with which query (especially when the input file contains a lot of queries).

Answer (score 1):

Redirect stderr and stdout to file
(The queries are in stderr)

```
impala-shell -f 'filename' &>'output'
```

---

Demo

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ cat>filename
select 1;
select 2;
select 3;
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ impala-shell -f 'filename' &>'output'
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ cat output 
Starting Impala Shell without Kerberos authentication
Connected to quickstart.cloudera:21000
Server version: impalad version 2.5.0-cdh5.7.0 RELEASE (build ad3f5adabedf56fe6bd9eea39147c067cc552703)
Query: select 1
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.16s
Query: select 2
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.02s
Query: select 3
+---+
| 3 |
+---+
| 3 |
+---+
Fetched 1 row(s) in 0.02s
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$
```